# MySql on ec2 linux instance stops taking data from import scripts

Tags: mysql, ruby, amazon-ec2, cron, chef-infra

I have a master server which imports data into a MySQL database on a slave server, and I'm trying to keep this running until the slave server reaches near capacity. I've done this by setting up cron jobs in a chef recipe, which runs 20 different ruby files every 15 mins. Everything works fine for about an hour, then the database stops taking entries. Can anybody shed some light on this please?

Things I've done:
1)logged into database and added entries. This is fine.
2)checked cron log to see that jobs have run. This is fine.

Here is one of my import files, but I don't think there is any problem with it

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'
require 'open-uri'

#my = Mysql2::Client.new(hostname,username,password,database)

con = Mysql2::Client.new(:hostname => 'ipaddress',
                    :username => 'username',
                    :password => 'password',
                    :database => 'database')        

con.query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,value VARCHAR(50));")

open('http://samplewebsite.txt').each_line do |word|
    word.split(" ").each do |str|
        outstring = str.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/,"")
        con.query("INSERT INTO words(value)
                VALUES('"+outstring+"');")
    end
end


puts "Done!"

con.close
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: After thinking about this for a little while I realized my mistake (and from people's answers below), I was hitting the same website too many times from my server, so I was getting blocked out. I've modified my recipes to go to different sites so they're more spread out and things are working fine now. Thanks to anyone wjo answered!

Comment: *"the database stops taking entries"* needs to be clarified.  What does this mean?  Errors?  Database not responsive?  Expected data isn't found there?  I am a MySQL DBA, but largely unfamiliar with Ruby -- doesn't `con.query()` have a return value that you should be checking?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. It's not an issue with the database, i can still input into the db manually. I've figured out that my server's ip is being blocked by the website I'm extracting data from after a number of requests, so I am going to try get around this today. I'll update my question later once I've worked out the ruffles so others can use it

Comment: This could be a firewall issue.  A common way to prevent brute-force attacks is to limit the number of connections to an endpoint in a certain length of time.  With UFW, for example, a ```ufw limit ...``` rule would do that.   You could test this easily by writing some code to repeatedly open a new connection and run a no-op query, counting the number of successful runs.  If it always runs the same number of times (after a long rest to clear any counters) this could be the issue.

Comment: Also, if this job fails, there's probably some useful exception info.  I'd consider wrapping the guts of this operation in a begin/rescue/end and put any exception messages so cron can email them to you.

Comment: @TomWilson thanks for reply, i realized this on Friday. I was querying the same site too many times.